# Process with parameters that are themselves statistical

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, exponential-distribution

I'd like to work with a pair of statistical processes such that the random variable from one process is the parameter of the second process. The simplest case I can imagine (and which is still appealing to me) is as such:

$$p(x,y|a,c) = p(x|a)p(y|c,x)$$

where $a, c$ are parameters and $p(x|a) = ae^{-ax}$ is the exponential distribution, and $y$ is exponential with parameter $\frac{c}{x}$,  $p(y|c, x) = (\frac{c}{x})e^{\frac{-c*y}{x}}$.

The difficulty, here, is that I can't seem to integrate over all $[0,\infty]$ and find the marginal distribution for $y$.

Q: Has this sort of formulation (process with parameters that are themselves statistical) been pursued and are there results out there that are published?

Comment: What do you mean with the `/` in $c/x$?

Comment: c/x is the parameter so that Exp(y|c/x) = (c/x)*exp(-c*y/x).

Comment: So, "/" means "divide".

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but you've got $P(x | a)$ and you've got $P(y | x, c)$ and you want $P(y | a, c)$. So you fix $a$ and $c$ and, a few thousand times sample from $P(x | a)$, then sample from $P(y | a, c)$ then throw away the column of $x$s.  Then you've got a sample from the right distribution. Summarise as appropriate.

Comment: True, I could do a simulation, but for my analysis, in which I want to fit to data, I need an analytical expression. Moreover, it is very disconcerting that the integration to obtain the marginal P(y) seems to be impossible. I can express the indefinite integral by expanding the Exp function in terms of a series, but upon integration I obtain the Gamma function and its singularities prevent definite integration.

Comment: OK. The analytic solution is an ordinary math problem, for which the parameter  / observation business is irrelevant, rather than a statistics or data analysis problem. This is fine, and someone may dive in, but there are probably better stack exchange sites to ask it on.

Comment: True, I have given an example that is a math problem. My question (marked with a Q) is: Has this sort of formulation (process with parameters that are themselves statistical) been pursued and are there results out there that are published?

Comment: The answer to that question is: yes, all Bayesian analyses traffic in similar situations. The parameters and the observations are random variables that will usually depend on each other in various ways, and integration is always the solution. The tools we use are nearly always monte carlo integration, which I used above.

Comment: The tools are *always* monte carlo? Perhaps I need to review some of the concepts of Bayesian analysis, and perhaps I've always seen BA in terms of a distinct separation of data and parameters. To me, this mixes things a bit, and, in the end I'm still interested in the data side of the equation P(y). Might be good to get input from other editors?

Comment: Almost always, yes. The integrations are too hard not to approximate. Some people use variational or Laplace approaches, but the general purpose go to tool is minx, eg Jags/bugs/Stan. And parameters are always really random variables (that's what makes bayesian statistics distinctive)

Comment: Mcmc not minx obviously (over enthusiastic phone)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on the discussion in the comments, your described situation can be viewed as a hierarchical model, like so:

$$X \sim Exp(a)$$

$$Y \sim Exp(\frac{c}{x})$$

There are certainly Bayesian models that provide analytic solutions, e.g. treating the $p$ parameter of a binomial distribution as a beta-distributed random variable. (These are also attractive for the interpretability of their parameters.)

But, when the relationships among variables get complicated, these methods tend to fall short. Where analytical methods are impossible, one can use a MCMC trace of any given parameter as an approximation of its posterior distribution. (Assuming one has properly assessed the chain for convergence.) Because the conjugate prior models that produce analytic solutions tend to be simple ones, their assumptions may be unrealistic for more elaborate processes. Even a [conjugate normal model](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/lectures/lecture5.pdf) assumes mean depends on precision (p. 5).

MCMC allows us to work around the absence of analytic solutions. This is a commonly cited reason for the growth in popularity of Bayesian methods: Cheap computing power made them possible.

Answer (score 1):

Further to my comments, here's a worked example where we try to infer $a$ and $c$ on the basis of a sample of observed $x$ and $y$ pairs and the belief that the data is generated in the way you describe.

I'll use R and JAGS in this example.  First make the data in R:

```
set.seed(1234)
c <- 2 # true unknown values of c and a
a <- 1
```

Sample some $x$s according to an exponential dist with rate $a$

```
x <- rexp(100, a)
```

and for each x, sample a y from an exponential dist with rate $c/x$

```
y <- sapply(x, function(x){ rexp(1, rate=c/x) })
```

Bundle it into a data.frame

```
dd <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
```

and define a Bayesian model by specifying a data generating process for $x$ and $y$ and priors for unknown $a$ and $c$ in the form of an R function for R2jags to work with

```
mod <- function(){
  # how we think the data was made
  for (i in 1:100) {
    x[i] ~ dexp(a)
    y[i] ~ dexp(c / x[i])
  }
  # prior dists for unknown a and c
  a ~ dgamma(1, 2) 
  c ~ dunif(0, 10)
}
```

Now load the interface to JAGS

```
library(R2jags) # requires JAGS to be installed first
```

and compile a sampler that will sample from the posterior for this model

```
jmod <- jags(dd, 
             parameters.to.save=c('c', 'a'), 
             model.file=mod)
```

An initial round of sampling is actually sufficient (convergence statistic is here `Rhat`) so we look what the sampler has come up with

```
jmod

3 chains, each with 2000 iterations (first 1000 discarded)
n.sims = 3000 iterations saved
     mu.vect sd.vect    2.5%     25%     50%     75%   97.5%  Rhat n.eff
a          1.011   0.101   0.824   0.943   1.010   1.076   1.219 1.001  3000
c          1.954   0.194   1.592   1.819   1.948   2.079   2.351 1.001  3000
```

The marginal posterior means of $a$ and $b$ are 1.011 and 1.954 respectively with quantiles as shown above, etc.  In this case not too far from their true values of 1 and 2.

You can also summarise the joint posterior in any way you like from the samples themselves, but this shows the general approach.

Comment: And +1 to you, for the better answer :)

Comment: Conjugateprior, you and I might be coming from very different worlds! I appreciate your interest, but for me a red flag goes up, warning!, when I am unable to confirm that the "distribution" I've hypothesized can't be marginalized, integrated to give a pdf for one of the two data quantities. In my experience this sort of issue can come back to haunt you if you don't understand it. And, I suppose I'm something of a yellow-pad kind of guy. A forward simulation is not what I'm after. Cheers!

Comment: Really, this is my day for being told I don't know what I'm talking about. This isn't a forward simulation, except to generate data to demonstrate a posterior analysis.

Comment: But that's fine. Some future stackexchanger may yet find the response helpful.

Comment: I might be using incorrect terminology, then. I'm still worried about the lack of an analytic approach. Red flag! I'm going to pursue the "hierarchical model" terminology used by SeanEaster. Sometimes, just knowing what something is called can open up a new universe. Again, thank you.

Comment: Sure. For what it's worth, my code is simply an implementation of @SeanEaster's hierarchical model approach to your problem :-)